# How to connect to ElasticSearch from Apache Spark Service on Bluemix

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I use Apache Spark service on Bluemix to create demo (collecting/parsing twitter data).I want to transport Elastic Search.

I created my scala app according to the following URL [1]:

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

However, when using Jupyter notebook on Bluemix, I couldn't run my app properly. A special interpreter-aware SparkContext "sc" was already running, but I cloudn't add properties to "sc"  such as "es.nodes", "es.port" ,and so on to connect Elastic Search.

Q1. 
Does anyone know how to add extra properties to a special interpreter-aware SparkContext on Bluemix? In my local spark environment, it's easy to add.

Q2.
I tried to create another SparkContext as follows and use for streaming, but it was uncontrollable on Jupyter notebook..

```
var conf = sc.getConf
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes", "XXXXXXXX")
conf.set("es.port", "9020")
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val sc1 = new SparkContext(conf)
```

My procedure to create extra SparkContext may not be right, I think.
Does anyone know how to create 2nd SparkContext properly on Bluemix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're already setting the properties on the configuration object within the existing SparkContext.

These lines (correcting what I assume is a typo) should be setting the option on the existing SparkContext's configuration:

```
val conf = sc.getConf
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes", "XXXXXXXX")
conf.set("es.port", "9020")
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
```

You mentioned you couldn't add these properties -- can you elaborate on the problem it was causing doing it this way?

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I mistake my codes. I modified that, it worked.